# function wont use the updated state if the setState function was called after execution began in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to to control the speed of which the state changes (board) with a sleep function that gets a value,
the value is controlled by a slider component which updates the state(speed).
the problem is when I try to change the value of the delay(speed) after the function(handlePlayClick) began.
then the value the function uses is the initial one before the change.

```
const [board, setBoard] = useState(createBoard(9));
  const [steps, setSteps] = useState();
  const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(200);
```

```
const handlePlayClick = async () => {
    const allSteps = deepCopy(steps);

    for (let i = 0; i < allSteps.length; i++) {
      setBoard(allSteps[i]);
      await sleep(speed);
    }
  };

const hanleSpeedChange = (e, v) => {
    setSpeed(v);
  };
```

```
<Slider
        className={classes.slider}
        value={speed}
        min={1}
        max={2000}
        onChange={hanleSpeedChange}
      />
```

the sleep function:

```
export default (ms) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to ensure that you always have the updated value of speed even after the function has been called is to use the useRef Hook:

```
  const speedRef = useRef(200);

  const hanleSpeedChange = (e, v) => {
    speedRef.current = v;
    setSpeed(v);
  };

  const handlePlayClick = async () => {
    const allSteps = deepCopy(steps);

    for (let i = 0; i < allSteps.length; i++) {
      setBoard(allSteps[i]);
      await sleep(speedRef.current);
    }
  };
```